# Spring 4: Rest WebServices: getting 406 for get request but not for Post request

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I have a web service /ws/forgetPassword. When I access it using get, I am getting

```
<html><head><title>VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.3.RELEASE/7.0.42.A.RELEASE - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.3.RELEASE/7.0.42.A.RELEASE</h3></body></html>
```

But when I converted it to Post, It worked fine and I get following response.

```
{
httpResponse: "200"
httpMessage: "OK"
resetPasswordUrl: "If your email is registered with us, an email will be sent to you with further instructions."
}
```

Post Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgetPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RestResponseWrapper forgotPassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        RestResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new RestResponseWrapper();

        try {
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            logger.debug("Email " + email);
            UserCes userCes = getService().getUserByEmail(email);
            if (userCes != null) {

                String validationCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(40);
                ForgotPassword forgotPassword = new ForgotPassword();
                forgotPassword.setCreatedBy(CesUtility.getUsername());
                forgotPassword.setCreatedOn(DateTimeUtility.getCurrentTime());
                forgotPassword.setEmail(email);
                forgotPassword.setValidationCode(validationCode);
                getBaseCrudService().save(forgotPassword);

                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                responseWrapper.setHttpResponse(HttpStatus.OK + "");
                responseWrapper.setHttpMessage(HttpStatus.OK.getReasonPhrase());
                responseWrapper.setResetPasswordUrl(getApplicationContext().getMessage("authauth.forgetpassword",
                        new Object[] { validationCode }, Locale.US));

            }else{
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
                responseWrapper.setHttpResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND + "");
                responseWrapper.setHttpMessage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseWrapper.setHttpResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR + "");
            responseWrapper.setHttpMessage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase());
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseWrapper;
    }
```

My Get Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgetPassword/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RestResponseWrapper forgotPassword(@PathVariable final String email, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    RestResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new RestResponseWrapper();

    try {
        logger.debug("Email " + email);
        UserCes userCes = getService().getUserByEmail(email);
        if (userCes != null) {

            String validationCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(40);
            ForgotPassword forgotPassword = new ForgotPassword();
            forgotPassword.setCreatedBy(CesUtility.getUsername());
            forgotPassword.setCreatedOn(DateTimeUtility.getCurrentTime());
            forgotPassword.setEmail(email);
            forgotPassword.setValidationCode(validationCode);
            getBaseCrudService().save(forgotPassword);

            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            responseWrapper.setHttpResponse(HttpStatus.OK + "");
            responseWrapper.setHttpMessage(HttpStatus.OK.getReasonPhrase());
            responseWrapper.setResetPasswordUrl(getApplicationContext().getMessage("authauth.forgetpassword",
                    new Object[] { validationCode }, Locale.US));

        }else{
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
            responseWrapper.setHttpResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND + "");
            responseWrapper.setHttpMessage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseWrapper.setHttpResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR + "");
        responseWrapper.setHttpMessage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase());
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("response.getContentType(): " + response.getContentType());
    logger.info(responseWrapper.toString());
    return responseWrapper;
}
```

So

1. Why I am getting 406 on get request.
2. I want to use get request for forgot password in the format: "/ws/forgetPassword/abc@example.com"

Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 406 means  that the `Accept` header is set to a type that the server cannot deliver. For example if you set `Accept: application/json` but the server delivers responses in `text/plain`, a 406 error would usually be returned.

Comment: but as you can see, I am not setting this anywhere. Where is it's being set and how to fix it? I searched on-line and same answer, but I am not getting out of the issue.

Comment: I can't see that this is not set. You have only posted server side code, the headers are set on the client side. What do you use on the client side to perform the requests?

Comment: i am using url in web browser for get request and also chrome rest ad-don